# SSH Library for Blackberry Application

Tags: mobile, ssh, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I'm looking for some SSH Library for a Blackberry Application, because I'm developing with Momentics IDE and I need to launch a command to SSH Server. Googling I found nothing and here as well.

Someone has an idea?

I'm talking about a QML/C++ Application.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the SSL documentation on the [developer web site](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_comm/networking/tutorial_use_ssl.html)?

Comment: Also according to the following link ssh is supposed to be available as a command. It isn't available in the simulator I have, which is all I can get at until I get home: https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/core/com.qnx.doc.neutrino.utilities/topic/s/ssh.html

Comment: Thank you again. So, I could try to use a system() call to ssh too!